# Efficient PRNG for WASM and x86_64?

Tags: random, web, rust

For a game I am finishing, I need a random sequence that can be generated in Wasm and in the server, yielding the same result.

This generated 64-bit(or more if supported by WASM) numbers sequence is up to 64MB long and should be the exact same once generated on the server side or in the client (WASM). It should be modern as of the time of this question and reproductible, using the same seed.

Currently, I use Mersenne Twister because it is the algorithm I always used, and it works OK. But I need the maximum performance while still having the least repeating sequence up to the final size.

I read about the PCG, xorshift but still cannot decide because I don't have the required knowledge to make a good decision.

Performance, factual randomness, reproductibility (same inputs, same output), WASM and x86_64 are my requirements.

I use Rust for this code.

Which should I go for to replace Mersenne ?

Edit:
I currently go for Xoshiro256PlusPlus.

Comment: I've been using PGC, xorshift (or variants thereof) to good effect in my game which does on-the-fly procedural generation and requires a _lot_ of random numbers, but I'm not enough of a statistician to say how good it is. 64MB of random numbers is not very many numbers, not enough to expose many of the possible flaws, so if speed is important I'd focus on that rather than passing every statistical test.

Comment: @MadMan: yes that's small; did you have one that your preferred using ? One that was a bit ahead the others in your experience ? xorshift could be the most efficient for my use I guess